# Can't assign requested address in php artisan serve

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am having a hard time figuring this one out. I was just setting up a new machine, and can't get `php artisan serve` to work. Gives me the following error. Also, note, I just did a fresh XAMPP install.

`Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
[Wed Dec 24 14:06:35 2014] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Can't assign requested address)`

I have stopped the apache server for the Mac, and even XAMPP. Going to 127.0.0.1 or localhost doesn't give me "It works!" anymore. Even then, when I do, `php artisan serve` for my fresh Laravel application, it just shows up that error. How do I fix this. I uninstalled older XAMPP and started from scratch.

**Updates**

If I do `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` it works. However, I'd like to know what's happening and a potential solution to this. Moreover, I have this in my `/etc/hosts` at the end `127.0.0.1 Alis-MacBook-Pro.local`. Putting `Alis-MacBook-Pro.local` in address bar does show `It works!`

Comment: Are you server listen on 80 or 8000?

Comment: How do I find that out? By the way I have this in my `/etc/hosts` at the end  `127.0.0.1 Alis-MacBook-Pro.local`. Putting `Alis-MacBook-Pro.local` in address bar does show `It works!`